# How do I change the state of a SWITCH using an AccessibilityService

Tags: java, android, kotlin, accessibility

I am a beginner in the Kotlin language. I wanted to know if there was a way to change the state of the SWITCH as shown in the picture. I want help. I tried this method and it did not work.

```kotlin
class MyAccessibilityService : AccessibilityService() {

    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent) {
        if (event.source!=null){

            val nodeList = rootInActiveWindow?.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText("Mobile networks ")


            if (nodeList != null) {
                if (nodeList.size > 0) {


                    nodeList[0]?.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK)
                    println("clicked")

                }else{
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
}
```

this my accessibilty xml

```xml
<accessibility-service
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:canRequestEnhancedWebAccessibility="true"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:packageNames="@null"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
    />
```

code MainActivity

```
button.setOnClickListener{
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                startActivity(Intent(android.provider.Settings.Panel.ACTION_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY))
            }
        }
```

[image: this my image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjIVv.jpg